# My sidebar overlaps when resizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

when viewed full screen, the sidebar appears fine. The moment I start to make the screen smaller, the sidebar then overlaps the other container. I've tried fiddling with the bootstrap code but I'm stuck - can anyone advice what I should be changing?

[image: Normal]

[image: Overlapped]

```
<div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1 blog-sidebar">
          <div class="sidebar-module sidebar-module-inset">
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/womendigitalnomads/" target="_blank" class="btn-social btn-facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>

              <a href="https://www.instagram.com/womendigitalnomads/" target="_blank"><img src="images/homepagebanner.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Instagram"></a>
    </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.sidebar-module {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 -15px 15px;
    border-left: solid 1px #e1e1e1;
}

.sidebar-module-inset {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.sidebar-module-inset p:last-child,
.sidebar-module-inset ul:last-child,
.sidebar-module-inset ol:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle

Comment: Did you use `float:right` on the sideba?

Comment: Please post a working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try to use width with % on .sidebar-module

Maybe it resizes properly